# If R is integral domain, Q field of fractions and I an ideal. Prove $I_Q \cong Q \otimes _R I \rightarrow Q\otimes _R R \cong Q$ is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

If R is integral domain, Q field of fractions and I an ideal then prove the induced map $I_Q \cong Q \otimes _R I \rightarrow Q\otimes _R R \cong Q$ is an isomorphism.

I know how to prove $I_Q\cong Q$ since there is an isomorphism between localization of modules and tensoring it with the field of fractions. And $Q\otimes _R R \cong Q$ is well-know property of tensors. But I don't know how to prove the isomorphism between $I_Q\rightarrow Q$.

Comment: Minor quibble, but you need $I \neq 0$ for this to be true.

Answer (score 1):

$Q \otimes_R I \rightarrow Q \otimes_R R = Q$ is injective since $Q$ is a localization over $R$ and localizations are flat.

For surjectivity, let $a/b \in Q$ , and $i \in I$. Then, $\frac{a}{ib} * i = a/b $, so a preimage is $\frac{a}{b} \otimes i$.

Comment: Thanks David. I understood surjectivity but not njectivity. $Q$ is localization over $R$ but how to prove localizations are flat? Couldn't we solve injectivity this way - Let $\frac{a}{b}⊗ i↦0$. Then how to show $\frac{a}{b}⊗i=0$?

Comment: See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HT